# How to send data from MQL4 into Socket

Tags: python, socket.io, mql4

Now, I trying to send the real-time data from MQL4. Into the socket server build by Python-Flask

My MQL4 using socket-library-mt4-mt5.mqh. But i don't how to handle the event to the socket.

My socket server

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/')
def sessions():
    return render_template('index.html')


def messageReceived(methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('message was received!!!')

@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json, methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('received my event: ' + str(json))
    socketio.emit('my response', json, callback = messageReceived)
```

My MQL4 code, As Socket client

```
#define SOCKET_LIBRARY_USE_EVENTS
#include <socket-library-mt4-mt5.mqh>

string Hostname = "127.0.0.1";
ushort ServerPort = "5000";

ClientSocket * glbClientSocket = NULL;

int OnInit() 
{
return NULL;
}

void OnDeinit(const int reason)
{
    if (glbClientSocket) {
        delete glbClientSocket;
        glbClientSocket = NULL;
        }
}

void OnTick()
  {
    if (!glbClientSocket) {
      glbClientSocket = new ClientSocket(Hostname, ServerPort);
      if (glbClientSocket.IsSocketConnected()) {
         Print("Client connection succeeded");
      } else {
         Print("Client connection failed");
      }
        }

    if (glbClientSocket.IsSocketConnected()) {
      string strMsg = Symbol() + "," + DoubleToString(SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(), SYMBOL_BID), 6) + "," + DoubleToString(SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(), SYMBOL_ASK), 6) + " Hello from MQL \n";
      glbClientSocket.Send(strMsg);
    } else {
        }
   if (!glbClientSocket.IsSocketConnected()) {
      // Destroy the server socket. A new connection
      // will be attempted on the next tick
      Print("Client disconnected. Will retry.");
      delete glbClientSocket;
      glbClientSocket = NULL;
   } 
 }
```

And i check The connection it's work, But still wrong the method 
As you see the my MQL4 code it's doesn't have the handle event function

```sh
127.0.0.1 - - [2019-08-29 13:25:36] "AUDUSD,0.672250,0.672360 Hello from MQL" 400 - 0.000403
<socket fileno=10 sock=127.0.0.1:5000 peer=127.0.0.1:37348>: Invalid HTTP method: 'AUDUSD,0.672260,0.672360 Hello from MQL \n'
```

The question is how to handle event like socket.on('my event') in javascript. Into my MQL4 code.